# Template Alias failing when I try to use it in a function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I am trying to use template type aliasing, but when I use it in a function my idea fails, as in example below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
using vec_T = std::vector<T>;

template <typename T>
T sum_vector(vec_T vec) // T sum_vector(std::vector<T> vec)
{
  T sum = 0;
  typename vec_T::iterator it; // typename std::vector<T>::iterator it;
    for (it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it)
      {
         sum += *it;
      }
   return sum;
}
```

Compiling the above code fails with the following error:

> error: template declaration of ‘T sum_vector’  T sum_vector(vec_T vec)
>
> error: missing template arguments before ‘vec’  T sum_vector(vec_T
>   vec)

If I used commented lines instead the code works fine. I really don't understand what I missing here, my understanding was that after `using X = Y`, compiler would just place `Y` where I have `X`, so where is the error coming from? How should I go about fixing this?

Comment: I never worked with this, but my guess is it should be `vec_T<T>`

Comment: [OT]: You may use `std::accumulate` instead of your own loop.

Comment: As an aside, `std::accumulate` already does pretty much what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between `using X = Y` and `using vec_T = std::vector<T>;` is that the former is a type alias and the latter is an alias template (or template alias, whatever.) The first form is essentially a typedef. The second form doesn't automatically substitute `T`. You need to *specialize* it. What you put between the angle brackets `<>` is substituted for `T` in the alias template. `vec_T<int>` becomes `std::vector<int>`.

§ 14.6/2

> When a *template-id* refers to the specialization of an alias
>   template, it is equivalent to the associated type obtained by
>   substitution of its *template-arguments* for the *template-parameters*
>   in the *type-id* of the alias template.
>
> ```
> template<class T> struct Alloc { /∗ ... ∗/ };
> template<class T> using Vec = vector<T, Alloc<T>>;
> Vec<int> v;
>  // same as vector<int, Alloc<int>> v;
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, now the error messages makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use

```
template <typename T>
T sum_vector(vec_T<T> vec)
```

and in your case, you may take argument by const reference:

```
template <typename T>
T sum_vector(const vec_T<T>& vec)
```